# Change Python Version Path

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I've been coding in Python 3 for a while now, and was looking to add a new module. After running the pip command I realized that it was downloading the new modules in my Python 2.7 folder. How do I change my path to 3.7, so when downloading modules it will automatically download here?

Comment: Can you specify the OS you are working on ? Instructions would depend on that.

Comment: Regardless. please search before asking; we get multiple questions per day with this type of question.

Comment: Have you check it with pip3

Comment: @tripleee if lot of people, like my self, struggle with this, then their should be a decent solution. For example, a tool, were you can easily switch between different installations...

Comment: @Jomme Indeed; that is why we want you to search before asking, because we have excellent answers for this precise topic already. Noise questions like this one with too few details and no response from the OP to requests for clarification dilute the search results and help no-one.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your environment variables, and edit them so that the path that contains the `pip.exe` corresponding to the Python 2.7 version is removed, and replace it with the path to the `pip.exe` corresponding to the Python 3 version, if that path is not already in the environment variables.